# User input to find data in CSV and then search through JSON dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, validation, data-science

I'm new to programming and I've been trying to figure out how to use a CSV file to access data within a JSON. Basically, I want to take 3 user inputs, search through the CSV and store information in variables that can then be used to access location data within a nested dictionary (there are 4000 entries like this):

```
f = open('wine.csv','r')
drinks = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
menu = []
for line in drinks:
    menu.append(line)

data = r.json

 {‘product’: {‘Wine’: ‘Bordeaux’,
   'name': ‘Le chateau;'},
  ‘year: ’2002,
  ‘price’: None,
  ‘size’: {’Bottle’: ‘70cl’,
   ‘country’: ‘France’,
   'location': {'latitude': '43.5912',
    ’taste’: {‘Fruit’: Blackberry, ‘Other’: ‘Smoke’},
    'longitude': '3.2584'},
   'context': '',
   ‘shop ID: ‘44djajj3h4488fhhahg1998743371’,
   'id': 83316647,
   ‘shop ’: ‘Wholesale’,
   ‘orderby’: ’09-11’}},
```

The first bit of code for the CSV file is this:

```
i = input("Please enter up to 5 locations: ")
for c in menu:
    if i == c[1]:
        loc = i
        lat = c[3]
        long = c[2]
```

When the user types in a location, it will store the latitude and longitude in variables. Then I want to use those to find every time that location appears in the dataset.

This is what I've tried:

```
for x in data:
    if loc == x['size']['location']['latitude'] and lat == x['size']['location']['longitude']:
       loc2.append(loc)
     
    count = len(loc2)

    dictionary[loc] = {'Lat':lat,'Long':long, 'Sales': count}
```

I keep getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers". Doing it in a function way sort of works, but I'm not good enough to do the input validation as well (or understand why its working!):

```
def locations (*loc):
    dictionary = {}
    for x in loc_3:
        for c in stuff:
            if x == c[1]:
                loc = x
                lat = c[3]
                long = c[2]
    try:
        for x in data:
            if loc == x['size']['location']['latitude'] and lat == x['size']['location']    ['longitude']:
       loc2.append(loc)

    except:
        print(dictionary)
    count =  len(loc2)
    dictionary[loc] = {'Lat':lat,'Long':long, 'Sales': count}
        
    return dictionary
```

An tips would be greatly appreciated. Its no exaggeration to say I've been trying to do this for about 100 hours!

Comment: You're doing `for x in loc` but then you're changing `loc` inside the loop.  What does the CSV file contain?

Comment: Ah that's my bad, corrected it but now it says "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lat' referenced before assignment". The CSV is literally just the Wine name and the latitude and longitude of its origin: 1,lechateau,43.5912,3.2584.. So the user inputs the wine name and the coords are added to the variables.

Comment: As a side note, I recommend that you learn about the `pandas` library and load each of your data files as a DataFrame. By doing so, tasks such as these will become much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is confusing.  Do you want the user to enter a wine name or a location?  Once you have a wine name, what do you want to do with it?  If the CSV has "lechateau" and the JSON has "Le chateau;", is that a match?  Why?

Here's how to read the CSV and how to look up a wine.

```
import csv

def readcsv(filename):
    wines = {}
    for row in csv.reader(open(filename)):
        wines[row[1]] = (row[0],float(row[2]),float(row[2]))
    return wines

wines = readcsv("wine.csv")

wine = input("Enter a wine name")
if wine in wines:
    print( "Location:", wines[wine][1], wines[wine[2]] )
else:
    print( "That wine is not in the list." )
```

Comment: This bit works great! But then the problem I'm having is finding the wines in the JSON dictionary using the lat and longitude. Sorry I didn't explain clearer:

So you type the wine name in, and the Latitude/Longitude are saved in separate variables. And then those variables are used to search through the dictionary and append the number of wines from that location to a list.  

 for x in dict:
            if loc == x['size']['location']['latitude'] and lat == x['size']['location']    ['longitude']: 
list.append(x)

I'll get there I'm sure! Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Well, sort of.  You want `if lat == ...['latitude'] and long == ['longitude']`, not loc and lat.